# C# WPF ListBoxItems in Listbox Left Click Event

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, mouseevent, listboxitem

I have a `listbox` in which i add `textblock` and  `listboxitem` in each row.
Xml look like this :

```
 <ListBox x:Name="DatabaseBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Book}">
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <DockPanelOrientation="Horizontal" Width="auto" Height="22">
         <Image x:Name="ToggleFavoriteImage" Width="10" Height="10" Tag="{Binding Tag}" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding City}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Author}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Country}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
      </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

What i want to do is have an `Mouse Event` for each of them and get the `Text` from `TextBlock` and the `Content` from `ListBoxItem`. I managed to get `TextBlock` `Text` like this :

```
 StringBuilder SName = new StringBuilder();
 var name = sender as System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock;
 SName.Append(name.Text);
```

But when i try to do the same in  `ListBoxItem` nothing happens. It seems like i neither can make selected any of them. Feels like something is infront of `ListBoxItem`. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Why you use ListBoxItem inside of ItemTemplate? ListBoxItem is automatically the container for each item. To display content use `ContentControl` or `ContentPresenter`.

Comment: What use should the Mouse Event achieve?